# django local_settings import error

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I would like to import a local_settings.py file (which is not in my VCS system) for overriding the DATABASES settings from settings.py

For this purpose I added those lines at the very end of my settings.py file.

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print('Unable to load local_settings.py:')
```

When I use a `python manage.py diffsettings` I see that the DATABASES settings from settings.py is not changed and I get the message `Unable to load local_settings.py:`

I would like to know why import failed.

This is my project folder architecture:

```
my_project_folder/
   my_project_folder/
       settings.py
       urls.py
       local_settings.py
       etc...
   app1/
   app2/
   static/
   manage.py
   docker-compose.yml
   etc...
```

This is the content of my local_settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db_my_project',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

And this is the content of the DATABASES settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'my_project',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because your forget the `.` in front of `local_settings.py` (relative import). Try `from .local_settings.py import *`, also check that there is an `__init__.py` in the current folder.

Concerning settings, I recommend you to store your settings in a `settings` folder. And create a setting file for each environment. Create a `base.py` file, which contains base settings and then import it in all other settings files.

Here is the structure :

```python
├── project_name
│   ├── project_name
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── dev.py
│   │   │   ├── staging.py
│   │   │   └── prod.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
...
```

And a settings file (**E.g** :`dev.py` or `local.py`) :

```python
try:
    from .base import *
except ImportError:
    print('Unable to import base settings file:')

# ...
```

Use always relative imports when it's possible.

Concerning databases, you shouldn't configure them in `base.py`. Declare them in each specific settings files.

Answer (score 2):

`from rororo.settings import inject_settings`

in the end of your's settings.py

`inject_settings('settings_local', locals(), True)`